# Deploying MVC ASP .Net web application on office localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, deployment, localization, localhost

I have created a web application using SQL Server as a database.

My client don't provide internet access to his employees.

So how can i deploy a MVC web application there so that it can be accessed by everyone which are connected to each other locally.

Comment: Is given below answer useful for you?

Comment: @KeertiSystematixInfotech can you go through the steps so that I can try it on my machine before deploying on clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Publish your web application by right click on your application and select publish option to a local folder on your file system.
2. Provide published code to you client's IT group.
3. Put your database inside App_Data folder
4. If MVC framework is not installed on client server machine then you will have to request you client install MVC framework on server machine and then configure application on IIS.

For help you can check given below link -

[How do I deploy MVC3 Hello World App to localhost and configure IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500487/how-do-i-deploy-mvc3-hello-world-app-to-localhost-and-configure-iis)